# Hacer que un control interno de un control detecte el DragEnter y/o DragOver

Tags: c#, windows-forms, drag-and-drop, agarrar-y-soltar

Estoy codificando un formulario donde tengo que hacer es arrastrar un item de un *ListView* a un *Control de Usuario* que contiene un *FlowLayerPanel*.

Este control de usuario y tiene diferentes comportamientos como agregar nuevos controles internos al *FlowLayerPanel*. Al agregar un control interno tiene un comportamiento por defecto de que acepta *drag and drop* de los items del *ListView*.

[image: DragAndDrop]

Mi problema es que el drag and drop es solamente capturado por el control padre y no por los controles internos como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: NivelesDeControl]

Según especulaciones mías, al parecer, la superficie del control padre está por encima de los controles internos que agrego y, por ende, la captura del drag and drop es solamente capturada por este control y no los controles internos.

¿Cómo hago para que el drag and drop sea detectado por el control interno y no por el control padre que lo contiene?

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo actual que tienes?

Comment: A parte de agregar e código con el que intentas capturar el drag and drop, ¿a qué te refieres cuando hablas de control externo e interno? ¿con control externo te refieres a control de usuario o a FlowLayerPanel? ¿con control interno te refieres a algún control definido en el control de usuario o a otros controles que creas dinámicamente?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se produce porque activas el evento DragEnter / DragOver solo en el contenedor. Si quieres que los controles arrastrados también cotrolen el evento, has de activarlo también en estos. Como los controles que contenga se decidirán al usar la aplicación, puedes activar el evento sobre cada objeto arrastrado sobre el contenedor en tiempo de ejecución, al controlarse el DragEnter / DragOver (del contenedor).

Los eventos en C# se activan y controlan por objeto. Un container es un tipo de objeto, como  el que comentas, es un objeto que contiene controles (objetos); Los eventos activados en el container, se controlan respecto al container, no respecto a los controles que contiene, a no ser que sean activados también en estos.